# Receive information in for loop produces strange error

Tags: c++, mpi, race-condition

I am trying to broadcast parts of an array composed of objects from the master node to the workers using for loops in the `MPI` library. I am having problems with the `Recv`steps. Generally speaking, I am open to any recommendation as I think there are simpler ways to address my problem. In my code, compiling each individual `MPI_Send`/`MPI_Recv` works perfectly, but not all together at once.

```
  if(rank==0){
    for(unsigned int r=1; r < com; r++){ //r is the node identifier
      for(int org = 0; org < NEAT::pop_size; org++){
        ...
        std::vector<NEAT::Trait*> gen_traits = ...; 
        struct traits sent_traits[num_traits];

        for(int id = 0; id < num_traits; id++){
          sent_traits[id].trait_id = gen_traits[id]->trait_id;
          ...and other stuff
        }

        MPI_Isend(&num_traits, 1, MPI_INT, r, org, parallel_2, &reqs_2[org]);
        MPI_Isend(&sent_traits, 1, mpi_trait, r, org, parallel_3, &reqs_3[org]);
```

Compiling up to here with the respective MPI_Recv (see following) works. The strange part comes hereafter: as soon as I include `Recv` of the vector of nodes the program crashes.

```
      struct nodes sent_nodes[num_nodes];
      for(int id = 0; id < num_nodes; id++){
        sent_nodes[id].node_id = gen_nodes[id]->node_id;
        if(gen_nodes[id]->nodetrait==0){
          sent_nodes[id].trait_id = 0;
        ...
      }
      
      MPI_Isend(&num_nodes, 1, MPI_INT, r, org+1, parallel_4, &reqs_4[org]); 
      MPI_Isend(&sent_nodes, 1, mpi_node, r, org+1, parallel_5, &reqs_5[org]); 
    }
  }
}

MPI_Barrier;
if(rank!=0){
    for(int org = 0; org < num_orgs ; org++){
      /*this first part is ok*/ 
      traits rcvd_traits[num_rcvd_traits];
      MPI_Recv(&num_rcvd_traits, 1, MPI_INT, 0, org, parallel_2, &status);
      MPI_Recv(&rcvd_traits, 1, mpi_trait, 0, org, parallel_3, &status);

      std::vector<NEAT::Trait*> gen_traits;
      for(int id = 0; id < num_rcvd_traits; id++){
        traits p_trait = rcvd_traits[id];
        NEAT::Trait* build_trait = new NEAT::Trait(p_trait.trait_id, ....
      }
      /*INCLUDING THIS ADDITIONAL PART LEADS TO A CRASH*/ 
      int num_rcvd_nodes;
      nodes rcvd_nodes[num_rcvd_nodes];
      MPI_Recv(&num_rcvd_nodes, 1, MPI_INT, 0, org, parallel_4, &status);
      MPI_Recv(&rcvd_nodes, 1, mpi_node, 0, org, parallel_5, &status);

      std::vector<NEAT::NNode*> gen_nodes;
      for(int id = 0; id < num_rcvd_nodes; id++){
        nodes p_node = rcvd_nodes[id];
        NEAT::NNode* build_node = new NEAT::NNode(p_node.trait_id, p_node.type, p_node.gen_node_label, p_node.ftype, gen_traits);
        gen_nodes.push_back(build_node);
      } 
    }
    std::cout << "finished " << std::endl;
}   

MPI_Finalize();
```

I get the error:

```
===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   PID 124551 RUNNING AT joachim-X399-AORUS-PRO
=   EXIT CODE: 139
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Segmentation fault (signal 11)
This typically refers to a problem with your application.
```

I am inspiring myself from this toy example:

```
int rank, com, num_orgs;
MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
MPI_Status status;
MPI_Comm parallel_0 = MPI_COMM_WORLD;
MPI_Comm_rank(parallel_0, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(parallel_0, &com);
MPI_Request reqs[4000];

if(rank==0){

  for(int r=1; r < com; r++){

    for(int q=0; q < 100; q++){

      MPI_Send(&r, 1, MPI_INT, r, q, parallel_0);//, &reqs[r*(q+1)]);

    }
  }
}

if(rank!=0){
  for(int q=0; q < 100; q++){
    int rcvd;
    MPI_Recv(&rcvd, 1, MPI_INT, 0, q, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
  }
}

MPI_Finalize();
```

Comment: First you have to declare `rcvd_traits` **after** you receive `num_rcvd_traits`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: And not as a VLA if you want it to be C++.

Comment: Use `std::vector<traits>` instead of an array and resize it to `num_recv_traits` before receiving in it.

Comment: Thank very much to all of you for your hints and help. @GillesGouaillardet : a particular thank to you as it was an error on which I wasn't paying attention and which solved my problem. I would have never been able to find it myself as I was focusing on the mpi code.

Comment: @HristoIliev your tip is a good one, I will try it. Thanks a lot again.